# array_slice for associative array

Tags: php, arrays, slice, associative-array

I have an array with indexes as timestamps.
I tried `array_slice` to get all values between a time range but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$data = array_slice(["1549440811" => 1, "1549448226" => 2, "1551108588" => 3 ], 0, 1549460338);
```

I should get the `$data` as `["1549440811" => 1, "1549448226" => 2]` but it doesn't work that way.

To get the right data I have to use

```
$data = array_slice(["1549440811" => 1, "1549448226" => 2, "1551108588" => 3 ], 0, 2);
```

But the problem is the records can have random timestamps and no. of records. So I am unable to figure out the offset which is 2 in this case.

I know the code below with a few changes might work for small range but not for my timestamps as `$myrange` would have a lot of data.

```
$myrange = range(0,1549460338);
$output = array_intersect(["1549440811" => 1, "1549448226" => 2, "1551108588" => 3 ] , $myrange );
```

I am avoiding looping through the array as the array has a lot of data. Also I have a lot of timestamps to check. This code is a simplified logic of a bigger code with records from database indexed with timestamps.

Is there any other way I could get the desired data?

Comment: why you filtering array, why not filter in mysql query or whatever use you database??

Comment: @nageennayak i have a loop on data I get from database and the timestamp 1549460338 is of a record in the loop, I avoided querying the database in the loop to fetch the other data. I got the other data in one query indexed by timestamp instead

Comment: @nageennayak the other data that I am fetching is being reused by other records in the loop as well

Comment: is the array already sorted by timestamp?

Comment: @acd yes sorted

Answer (score 2):

Simple for-loop should do:

```
$arr = ["1549440811" => 1, "1549448226" => 2, "1551108588" => 3 ];
$range = "1549460338";
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($range > $k)
        break;
    $newArr[$k] = $v;
}
```

You can also use `array_filter` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)):

```
$filtered = array_filter( $arr,
    function ($key) use ($range) {return $range > $key;},
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

Example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/qoLhr)

**Edit:**

**Fastest way** (consider your array is **sorted**) is to extract the keys with `$keys = array_keys($arr);` and then search for the `$range` using binary search (`O(log(n))`) -> then use `array_slice` with that index.

Comment: I prefer not to loop as the data is too much.

Comment: @MehravishTemkar update the post using `array_filter` - is it better?

Comment: thanks. let me implement it in my code and get back to you

Comment: @MehravishTemkar on the backend, it would be loop

Comment: thanks. thousands of records in the array as well as for timestamps, avoiding things that would slow it down. @DanyalSandeelo

Comment: `array_filter` is still a loop tho

Comment: @MehravishTemkar - I added another way to how to do it - but it very much depends on your implementation. I believe the first option (`foreach` loop with the `break` will be the fastest and simplest)